# Adding extra Host details in Nagios

Tags: nagios

We are using Nagios to monitor our infrastructure, and i was wondering if there was any way to add extra information to a host (model, purchase date etc) Ideally i would like to be able to set this information from the front end web site.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible from the web interface (though you could add details to the config). Nagios is a monitoring tool, not a server inventory tool.

Comment: Thought as much, i might just put the information into the notes section on the host